# Binding and routing or url generation problem in Asp.NET Mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, routes

In my view the call below generates url ending with Tasks/Edit but I want it to generate url like Tasks/Edit/23

```
<%= Html.ActionLink<TaskController>("Edit Task", (x) => x.Edit("23"))%>
```

in Global.asax:

```
string taskController = NameResolver.NameOfController<TaskController>();
string editAction = NameResolver.NameOfAction<TaskController>(x => x.Edit(null));
routes.MapRoute(
       "EditTasks",
       "Tasks/Edit/{id}",
       new { controller = taskController, action = editAction, id = string.Empty });
```

I also have binding problem in this action. Values set from view is not binded to my Edit parameter. It comes null everytime and I have not set DefaultModelBinder anywhere. Here is the Edit action:

```
    public ActionResult Edit (string id)
    {
       //retrieve some data and pass it to view and return view
    }
```

So what can be the problem here? How can I solve url and binding problem? And yes I am a Asp.Net Mvc beginner :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Task", "Edit", new { id = "2" }) %>
```

Although why is your id a string and not an int?

Comment: Thanks a lot. For id thing it is not actually an integer, for simplicity I changed it this way in code sample. One more question: Can I use strongly typed action name, ie not "Edit", does Mvc has such utility?

Comment: @arch stanton: I can't see how you can use a strongly typed action name because Edit is a method not a class without some serious screwing around by parsing LINQ expressions. I'll give this a shot when I have time, but even if possible, it should never make it to production. It would be a bad hack that is not maintainable.

Comment: I heard MvcContrib supports those strongly typed usages like Html.ActionLink<TaskController>("Edit Task", (x) => x.Edit("23")). But not tried it myself.